# JQuery interval isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've made a small script to load a page into a div of another page, which gets refreshed every 5 seconds.

The page is loaded as expected, but the interval doesn't seem to work.

I already searched for a solution, but all threads are saying that my code should work like that. So I decided to post the full code here.

JQuery (and AJAX):

```
<script>
function load(){
    $('#chatload').load('/intern/chat/chatlogframe.php/?name=muster',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

load(); // run it on pageload
setInterval(function(){
    load() // this should run every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
</script>
```

The chatlogframe.php file contains a SQL Select query. The data should be reloaded every time the scipt gets executed.

UPDATE:

I checked the Chrome Console where it says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unwrap is not a function`

I don't think that the function is wrong, but maybe it helps.

UPDATE 2:

Heres the html div:

```
<div id='chatload'></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add a ";" at the end of load. Have a look into your console log in your browser for any error. Also try a console.log in your interval function.

Comment: Thanks! But it still does not work. I checked the chrome console and get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unwrap is not a function`

Comment: Are you sure the jQuery file is being loaded? The is telling that it is not, as the jQuery is not existent. UPDATE: Sorry didn't saw that it is loading fine on comments below. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. May be there's some issue with your code in `$('#chatload').load('/intern/chat/chatlogframe.php/?name=muster',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });`

.unwrap() could be possible issue but to isolate that you would need to post your sample HTML container.

```js
function load() {
  console.log("Do something");
  $('#chatload').load('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', function() {
    $(this).unwrap();
  });
}

load(); // run it on pageload
setInterval(function() {
  load() // this should run every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chatload"></div>
```

Comment: The file gets loaded without problems. Only the Interval isn't working

Comment: `.unwrap()` could be possible issue but to isolate that you would need to post your sample HTML container.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: you can place `debugger;` right before `$(this).unwrap()` line and see what's the state of $(this) during each interval. That should navigate you to the issue.

Comment: I see what i've done wrong. The script is used 3 times on the page by beeing created with php in a loop. Only the last generated script gets executed and not the others. Is there a way to use the scripts multiple times on the same page?

Comment: What's the purpose of creating multiple snippet of the same code? You can write up JS code once and then on-some-event call that script to run